# How to update a SQL table column which has xml data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Server table (`myTable1`) which has a column (`chtml`) of type `ntext`.

The column stores data as XML text:

```
<root>
    <StartOne>
        <Value1>Michael, John MD</Value1>
        <Value2>English</Value2>
        <Value3>6900 Ocean Avenue</Value3>
        <Value4>908-783-0909</Value4>
        <Value5>IM</Value5>
    </StartOne>
</root>
```

I can query the table using the following:

```
select
    CONVERT(nvarchar(600), CAST ([chtml] as XML).query('/root/StartOne/Value2')) AS [Value5]
from 
    [myTable1]
```

I have a staging table which has rows of data with `Value1` being the unique value in both table.

Staging table (`StageTable`):

```
Value1              Value2      Value3              Value4          Value5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Michael, Jogn MD    Spanish     6900 Ocean Avenue   734-090-1234    NULL
```

How can I write a query which will update each node in the `myTable1` table from the staging table.

I tried the following (Update `Value2` field in `myTable1` from the `Value2` field from `StageTable` if `Value2` field in `StageTable` matches the `Value1` value in `myTable1`):

```
UPDATE
    myTable1
SET
    myTable1.(CAST ([chtml] as XML).query('/root/StartOne/Value2')) = ST.Value2
FROM
    myTable1 MT
INNER JOIN
    StageTable ST ON MT.(CAST ([chtml] as XML).query('/root/StartOne/Value1')) = ST.Value1
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'.

How can I resolve the issue.

Comment: Why are you using the ntext datatype??? It has been deprecated since 2005 and is a serious pain to work with. Why not use a more appropriate datatype....like maybe xml?

Comment: @SeanLange Unfortunately it is querying a CMS database which I cannot change and it is using `ntext` as the column type.

Comment: Oh that's fun. You will probably have to parse out the xml and rebuild the xml with your new values. I doubt you can do this in a single step.

Comment: I am sure it will be fun :). Do you have a suggestion or a starting point of origin?

Comment: Well the syntax you are trying to use for cast doesn't make any sense. It should be CAST (myTable1.[chtml] as XML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code how we can update XML

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml;
SET @myDoc = '<root>
    <StartOne>
        <Value1>Michael, John MD</Value1>
        <Value2>English</Value2>
        <Value3>6900 Ocean Avenue</Value3>
        <Value4>908-783-0909</Value4>
        <Value5>IM</Value5>
    </StartOne>
</root>';
SELECT @myDoc;

-- update text 
SET @myDoc.modify('
  replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value1/text())[1]
  with     "new text "
');
SELECT @myDoc;
```

UPDATE: if Column datatype is `NTEXT`

```
declare @temp table
(
xmls ntext
)

insert into @temp values (N'<root>
    <StartOne>
        <Value1>Michael, John MD</Value1>
        <Value2>English</Value2>
        <Value3>6900 Ocean Avenue</Value3>
        <Value4>908-783-0909</Value4>
        <Value5>IM</Value5>
    </StartOne>
</root>');

declare @xml xml;
-- here we can put where clause OR loop
select @xml = cast(xmls as xml)
from @temp

set @xml.modify('
  replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value1/text())[1]
  with     "new text "
');

update @temp
set xmls = cast(@xml as nvarchar(max))

select * from @temp
```

Comment: Can you assist me with the `where` clause? Also, If I have a  table already with multiple column per row, how would that work? Thanks.

Comment: @SiKni8 i have mention only one column if we have multiple column in `@temp` table then we can use like `select @xml = cast(xmls as xml)
from @temp where id = 1`

Comment: What if I wanted to modify multiple XML tag? I tried to enter two separate `set @xml.modify('');` statement but it failed. Do I have to use one statement and separate each by commas?

Comment: Also do you know why I am getting this error: `XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding`

Comment: I asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230486/how-to-update-a-sql-table-column-with-xml-data